# How to put command with path output into variable when running ssh multipule commands

Tags: shell-script, ssh, variable, path

I want to write a bash script that will ssh to a remote machine, put the output of a "find" command into a variable, and then use the variable for later commands inside the ssh.
I know I can ssh to receive the path I need, and then ssh again to the same remote machine:

```
PATH=$(ssh $SERVER_NAME find /something/something_else | grep -G "end_of_the_file_i_need$")
```

But I want to save a bit of time trying to reconnect, and make the script more organized as to what I'm doing.
Would like, if possible to make something closer to this:

```
ssh $SERVER_NAME <<EOF
PATH=$(find /something/something_else | grep -G "end_of_the_file_i_need$")
...
...
...
EOF
```

In the second example, it tries to "find" the file from the original machine, and not from the one I connect to.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this must be a duplicate - basically command substitution `$(...)` as well as variable expansion are performed on the contents of the here document before `ssh` is called. How to fix that depends what else your snippet does i.e. whether you need ANY variable expansion or not (if not, you can quote or escape any part of the `EOF` word, like `'EOF'` or `\EOF`, to prevent expansion)

Comment: Please don't use `PATH` variable - PATH is special variable in Bash.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as
reserved by the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then
[wonder why](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27555060/7552) 
your [script is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28310594/7552).